# Validation Error, following reports have not been enabled for your account: identity

Tags: backend, webhooks

i am trying to implement Onfido to verify our customer's identities (Either Driving License or Passport) from our application (IOS and Android). We Implemented Onfido and generated Applicant ID from our applications (via SDK) and received it in back-end (At our server) and saved it with users info in our database.

I am trying to create check by performing API request same as per [Onfido documentation](https://documentation.onfido.com/) but i am getting "validation error". Here i am sharing JSON response below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "validation_error",
        "message": "There was a validation error on this request",
        "fields": {
            "base": [
                "The following reports have not been enabled for your account: identity. You can see the list of enabled reports using the /report_type_groups API endpoint. Please contact client-support@onfido.com if you have questions regarding your account setup."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As mention in the above error message. It emphasize to enable report from our dashboard but i am not able to find options to enable it from dashboard. I also tried to get list of  "Report Type Groups" from API endpoint but i am getting empty list.

My question are :

1. How exactly i can enable Report from Dashboard section?
2. How to create "Report Type Groups" from dashboard ?

   https://api.onfido.com/report_type_groups
   (currently it response as `Not Found`)
3. What i need to pass while creating CHECK from API in the `reports[][name]` parameter (In case of Driving License or Passport verification)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked these queries to Onfido tech support at api@onfido.com and as per my understanding these are the answers for the above questions.

1. How exactly i can enable Report from Dashboard section?
   **ANSWER:** You cannot enable reports from the dashboard or API. By-default their account has Document and Facial Similarity reports enabled. If you would like to add more report types please contact client-support@onfido.com.
2. How to create "Report Type Groups" from dashboard ?
   **ANSWER:** As stated in the documentation, you cannot add report type groups from the dashboard. Again, this can be done for you by contacting client-support@onfido.com.
3. What i need to pass while creating CHECK from API in the `key: reports[][name] parameter` (In case of Driving License or Passport verification)?
   **ANSWER**:  For document reports the `key: reports[][name]` should have `value: (str)document`. This is what you would pass for checking a passport, driving licence, identity card (including Aadhar) etc.

Please note that the Aadhar report is not a document check but verifies the Aadhar number supplied with the applicant object against a database. It can, of course, be run in conjunction with a document check to verify that the details on the document match the Aadhar database.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with `Onfido V2`

You need to check your `report_type_groups` by command below

```
curl https://api.onfido.com/v2/report_type_groups -H "Authorization: Token token=test_token"
```

If you have the KYC variant enabled on your account you must pass variant with the create check request. Something like this:

```
curl https://api.onfido.com/v2/applicants/APPLICANT_ID/checks -H "Authorization: Token token=test_token" -d "type=standard" -d 'reports[][name]=identity' -d 'reports[][variant]=kyc'
```

[Create an identity check](https://documentation.onfido.com/#create-an-identity-check) && [identity-verification](https://documentation.onfido.com/#identity-verification)